# get package path from plug-in

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a plug-in, and I need to get a path of XML file that exist within java package, my question is how can I get the path of the file?
when i'm running the project as is  i'm getting the file successfully but when i'm running the project as eclipse application the file located in anoter path.
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get every resource as InputStream with this line

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/yourpackage/namefile");
```

Hope this help.